# SFTP action in FinalBuilder always gets disconnected

Tags: sftp, finalbuilder

i have the final builder actions below

```
sftp connect
try
  sftp create directory
finally
  sftp disconnect
end
```

thing is the action always says "connection lost" at `sftp create directory`. i even insert a reconnect before that line but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contact FinalBuilder support and they will in turn contact us as developers of SFTP component. The problem is in the server, which gets confused by certain request and forcefully closes connection. We can diagnose the problem but fixing it would require cooperation with FinalBuilder team so we can't support you directly.